# Unable to perform a save on large broadcast variable join

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, out-of-memory, heap-memory, amazon-emr

I have two data frames, one is large `(df1)` which contains approx `290` million records with `900` attributes (50 GB parquet), and other is also a large file `(df2)` which contains around `290m` records but with 2 attributes (5Gb Parquet).

To improve the performance, I have created a broadcast variable in a data frame which contains two attributes `(df2)` and performed a join operation on these two data frames `(df1 and df2)`. Before joining I did a filter and tried to save it on s3, but it's killing my job with an outOfMemory error.

I am running this join on a two node `r3.8xlarge Amazon emr cluster`, each node contains `240GB` memory with driver memory around `50Gb` and executor memory around `20GB`.

It gave me an error on `driver.maxResultSize`, by saying it is not enough, so I have increased the `driver.maxResultSize` to around 10Gb.

**Each executor is given more than 20GB executor memory with 5 cores!!**

I have two questions in my mind:

1. Can I have a broadcast variable with such huge number of records, If I can have what the best memory config settings on spark are?
2. How can I change the by [default](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/DeveloperGuide//MemoryTuning.html) java heap size on amazon emr, Can someone give me the right command to do this or instructions?

Comment: try applying filter first on both Data frames and then apply action also try to repartition according to available memory explicitly. use G1 GC instead of normal one.

Comment: I am actually doing filter before I do join, and then I am running action. Regarding repartition, after filtering and joining the two data frames, I am selecting one column and performing a repartition (1) on one column and then saving it.

Comment: repartition(1) and action will only work when the worker more memory than the size of data frame.  i would suggest you to use persistence with memory and disk ser and more number of repartitions

Comment: Your points are not specific, I have already persisted df2, df1 I tried, I couldn't persist (because it's a very huge parquet file) and I must do repartition(1)